# Bookdown - theorem references within math?

Tags: html, r, bookdown

I am using Bookdown, and I would like to refer to a theorem in the middle of a mathematical derivation. The closest I have got is to use

```
\begin{align*}
b^2 &= c^2 -a^2  \text{ by Theorem @ref(thm:pythagoras)} \\
\end{align*}
```

where I have previously defined a theorem labelled `pythagoras` as follows

````
```{theorem, label="pythagoras"}
$c^2=a^2+b^2$
```
````

The pdf output renders as I would like:

[image: pdf output]

but the HTML does not:

[image: HTML does not].

Looking at the HTML source, the problem is that MathJAX has broken due to the inclusion of a link of the form `<a href=""></a>`. It works if I manually remove the hyperlink, however this is not a practical solution as I have quite a lot of these in my document.

Is there a way to fix this?